# Android biometric authentication invalid variables in AuthenticationCallback when using device credential

Tags: android, kotlin, android-biometric-prompt, android-biometric

I am using  `androidx.biometric:biometric:1.0.1` everything works fine but when I have a device without a biometric sensor (or when the user didn't set his fingerprint or etc) and I try to use [DeviceCredentials](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/biometric/BiometricPrompt.PromptInfo.Builder#setDeviceCredentialAllowed(boolean)) after doing authentication my function input data is not valid.

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private val TAG = MainActivity::class.java.name

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        findViewById<View>(R.id.first).setOnClickListener {
            authenticate(MyData(1, "first"))
        }

        findViewById<View>(R.id.second).setOnClickListener {
            authenticate(MyData(2, "second"))
        }
    }

    private fun authenticate(data: MyData) {
        Log.e(TAG, "starting auth with $data")
        val biometricPrompt = BiometricPrompt(
            this,
            ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(this),
            object : BiometricPrompt.AuthenticationCallback() {
                override fun onAuthenticationSucceeded(result: BiometricPrompt.AuthenticationResult) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "auth done : $data")
                }
            })

        val promptInfo = BiometricPrompt.PromptInfo.Builder()
            .setDeviceCredentialAllowed(true)
            .setTitle("title")
            .build()
        biometricPrompt.authenticate(promptInfo)
    }
}

data class MyData(
    val id: Int,
    val text: String
)
```

First I click on my `first` button, authenticate, then I click my `second` button and authenticate, then android logcat is like this:

```
E/com.test.biometrictest.MainActivity: starting auth with MyData(id=1, text=first)
E/com.test.biometrictest.MainActivity: auth done : MyData(id=1, text=first)
E/com.test.biometrictest.MainActivity: starting auth with MyData(id=2, text=second)
E/com.test.biometrictest.MainActivity: auth done : MyData(id=1, text=first)
```

as you see in last line MyData id and text is invalid! `autneticate` function input(data) is not the same when onAuthenticationSucceeded is called!

(if you try to test it be sure to use DeviceCredentials not biometrics, I mean pattern or password, unset your fingerprint)
Why data is not valid in callBack?

**it works ok on android 10 or with fingerprint**

I don`t want to use onSaveInstanceState.

Comment: did you try to create a custom `BiometricPrompt.AuthenticationCallback` and create your class instead and pass your parameter into the constructor?
or maybe keep the `MyData` param as Activity param and access that param instead?

Comment: Which Android version are you testing on? The androidx biometric library does slightly different things on Android Q compared to earlier Android versions.

Comment: @michael AVD Android P (9.0)

Comment: But I don't think the question is even related to Android!
it can be any callback
Am I missing anything?

Comment: I think it is related to android lifecycle somehow

Comment: @seyedJafari it didn't work: https://gist.github.com/faridfor/afb41424ef36a7197488efed9d2c07af

Comment: Hmmm... I've just copied your complete code and it worked on a google pixel 2 (Android 10). I've used pin input instead of fingerprint sensor.

Comment: no use API<29
its ok on Android 10

Comment: I think this problem is happening because of the `FragmentManager` and the way this library is handling the `Callback` class

Comment: Did you try moving your biometricPrompt out of authenticate() and converting it to a field in the activity, so that you can reuse the same instance?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you create a new instance of `BiometricPrompt` class, it adds a `LifecycleObserver` to the activity and as I figured out it never removes it. So when you have multiple instances of `BiometricPrompt` in an activity, there are multiple `LifecycleObserver` at the same time that cause this issue.

For devices prior to Android Q, there is a transparent activity named `DeviceCredentialHandlerActivity` and a bridge class named `DeviceCredentialHandlerBridge` which support device credential authentication. `BiometricPrompt` manages the bridge in different states and finally calls the callback methods in the `onResume` state (when back to the activity after leaving credential window) if needed. When there are multiple `LifecycleObserver`, The first one will handle the result and reset the bridge, so there is nothing to do by other observers. This the reason that the first callback implementation calls twice in your code.

**Solution:**
You should remove `LifecycleObserver` from activity when you create a new instance of `BiometricPrompt` class. Since there is no direct access to the observer, you need use reflection here. I modified your code based on this solution as below:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private val TAG = MainActivity::class.java.name
    private var lastLifecycleObserver: LifecycleObserver? = null

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        findViewById<View>(R.id.first).setOnClickListener {
            authenticate(MyData(1, "first"))
        }

        findViewById<View>(R.id.second).setOnClickListener {
            authenticate(MyData(2, "second"))
        }
    }

    private fun authenticate(data: MyData) {
        Log.e(TAG, "starting auth with $data")
        lastLifecycleObserver?.let {
            lifecycle.removeObserver(it)
            lastLifecycleObserver = null
        }
        val biometricPrompt = BiometricPrompt(
                this,
                ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(this),
                object : BiometricPrompt.AuthenticationCallback() {
                    override fun onAuthenticationSucceeded(result: BiometricPrompt.AuthenticationResult) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "auth done : $data")
                    }
                })

        var field = BiometricPrompt::class.java.getDeclaredField("mLifecycleObserver")
        field.isAccessible = true
        lastLifecycleObserver = field.get(biometricPrompt) as LifecycleObserver

        val promptInfo = BiometricPrompt.PromptInfo.Builder()
                .setDeviceCredentialAllowed(true)
                .setTitle("title")
                .build()
        biometricPrompt.authenticate(promptInfo)
    }
}

data class MyData(
        val id: Int,
        val text: String
)
```

Comment: Did you have any luck achieving this fix on a Fragment? I've tried fragment.lifecycle.removeObserver(it) and fragment.activity.lifecycle.removeObserver(it), but neither seem to fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

So it seems strange but I managed to get it working by introducing a parameter to `MainActivity`

here is the working code:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    var dataParam : MyData? = null

    companion object {
        private val TAG = MainActivity::class.java.name

    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        findViewById<View>(R.id.firstBtn).setOnClickListener {
            authenticate(MyData(1, "first"))
        }

        findViewById<View>(R.id.secondBtn).setOnClickListener {
            authenticate(MyData(2, "second"))
        }
    }


    private fun authenticate(data: MyData) {
        Log.e(TAG, "starting auth with $data")
        dataParam = data
        val biometricPrompt = BiometricPrompt(
                this,
                ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(this),
                object : BiometricPrompt.AuthenticationCallback() {
                    override fun onAuthenticationSucceeded(result: BiometricPrompt.AuthenticationResult) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "auth done : $dataParam")
                    }
                })

        val promptInfo = BiometricPrompt.PromptInfo.Builder()
                .setDeviceCredentialAllowed(true)
                .setTitle("title")
                .build()
        biometricPrompt.authenticate(promptInfo)
    }
}

data class MyData(
        val id: Int,
        val text: String
)
```

The output is now:

```
E/com.worldsnas.bioissuesample.MainActivity: starting auth with MyData(id=1, text=first)
E/com.worldsnas.bioissuesample.MainActivity: auth done : MyData(id=1, text=first)
E/com.worldsnas.bioissuesample.MainActivity: starting auth with MyData(id=2, text=second)
E/com.worldsnas.bioissuesample.MainActivity: auth done : MyData(id=2, text=second)
```

Comment: thank for your answer.
I want to find out a good solution, cause we can save data in plenty of places in android.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are asking about `setDeviceCredentialAllowed(true)`, it's safe to assume you aren't following [the recommended implementation](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/migrating-from-fingerprintmanager-to-biometricprompt-4bc5f570dccd) that uses `CryptoObject`. (Also check out this [blog post](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2019/10/one-biometric-api-over-all-android.html).)

The `setDeviceCredentialAllowed(true)` functionality will only work on API 21+, but you have multiple options for handling it in your app depending on your minSdkVersion.

**API 23+**

if your app is targeting API 23+, then you can do

```
 if (keyguardManager.isDeviceSecure()){
     biometricPrompt.authenticate(promptInfo)
 }
```

**API 16 to pre-API 23**

If your app must make the check pre API 23, you can use

```
if (keyguardManager.isKeyguardSecure) {
   biometricPrompt.authenticate(promptInfo)
}
```

`KeyguardManager.isKeyguardSecure()` is equivalent to `isDeviceSecure()` unless the device is SIM-locked.

**API 14 to API 16**

If you are targeting lower than API 16 or SIM-lock is an issue, then you should simply rely on the error codes in the callback `onAuthenticationError()`.

P.S. 
You should replace `private val TAG = MainActivity::class.java.name` with `private val TAG = "MainActivity"`.

Comment: I am targeting API 28. I don't have problem there. question is why this happens.

Comment: your `targetSdkVersion` is 28? What's your `minSdkVersion`?

Comment: minimum is API 21.